# Hop Gardening Considerations

Tags: hops, ingredients, grow

I have heard that planting hops at home you should plant the rhizome in a mound of sorts.

How large around should the mound be?
What type of soil amendments are best?
How tall should the trelis be for the first year of growth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hops should be grown in well-drained soil.  Mounding aids drainage, therefore may be unnecessary.  It should be about three feet in diameter.

Amend your soil with some organic matter like manure or grass clippings.

Your trellis should be able to support thirty pounds of bines growing twenty five feet (yes, in the first year).

Good luck.